# Support third-party cookies in WKWebView

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I want to support third-party cookies in an iOS application using WKWebView. Is there any way to support third-party cookies when the user has blocked all cookies in Safari's settings (Settings -> Safari -> Block Cookies -> Always)?

I have tried saving all cookies from the response and sending them in the request but it did not help.

Comment: Even now, in iOS 11, it doesn't seem possible in my testing. Regardless of what the user's Safari settings are. Still hoping for an official answer if this is true, because I can't determine third party cookie support for `WKWebView` from the documentation.